# LLVM Pass to allocate memory at specific addresses

Tags: c++, c, llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I'm trying to use an LLVM pass to transform a C/C++ program so that all memory allocations will occur only in a certain region of memory that I get to decide.

e.g. For the following code, I want to use an LLVM pass to start all memory allocations at address 0x10000:

```
// Test.cpp
int main()
{
    int x = 5;    // I want to allocate memory for this variable
                  // starting at address 0x10000

    int y = 6     // Memory allocated at 0x10004, since it's the second int

    return 0;
}
```

Does anyone know if this is possible to achieve via an LLVM pass? I already know I can use a pass to loop through all instructions in a program to find all alloca instructions, but I don't know how to transform a program so that alloca will allocate memory at a specific address.

Comment: Most modern operating systems randomize the running process's internal virtual address space, as a security measure.

Comment: I think alloca allocates from stack, therefore you cannot control the address, as current stack pointer needs to be used.

Comment: Replace the calls to alloca with ones to your own function, linked to the program, that will allocate in your dedicated region.

Comment: @Brian But do you know how to use an LLVM pass to dedicate a region of memory for allocation? So far my understanding is that even if I insert alloca instructions, all the memory allocation will occur on the regular stack. I have't yet figured out how to select a specific region of memory for all allocations to take place.

Comment: That transformation would effectively change all variables with automatic [storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) to static storage duration; you could achieve that effect by declaring the variables `static`. That's an incompatible semantic change; I'm not saying LLVM can't do it, but I'm certain it's not a standard transformation.

Comment: Replace all calls to alloca with calls to MY_alloca, which will allocate and manage the memory region.  Then as @rici notes, you also need to manage the freeing of these allocations at the end of the function.  So what you want to do is technically feasible...

Comment: @Brian I think I get what you're saying -- I need a custom implementation of alloca. But I'm not sure of how to implement this, do you have a high level idea of what the implementation might be like? I don't exactly know how to allocate memory at dedicated memory addresses even in C/C++.

Comment: @putiiii, mmap (Linux) and VirtualAllocEx (Windows) both allocate memory and have an optional parameter to place those allocations at a specific address.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [linker script](https://wiki.osdev.org/Linker_Scripts) to place a certain section at that address, and then use an LLVM pass to [place the relevant global/static variables at in that section](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1GlobalObject.html#a959c99adbdc7f8375cf866916c6b60f2).

However, x and y in your question are local to main(), and tend to live on the stack or perhaps even in a machine register. You know and I know that main() isn't going to call itself recursively, but the compiler tries really hard to allow recursion. Fighting that in a pass will not be simple, so *those* variables may not be easy to put in a specific section.

Comment: I looked into linker scripts, and it seems to be that it's possible to choose where stack memory is allocated too. In your answer you only mention placing global/static variables, but would there be issues with choosing the location of the stack for local variables?

Comment: That's right, you can choose where the stack is, but the linker doesn't locate individual variables within the stack's address space. It only locates the stack itself. The address of a stack variable depends on how much stack space has been used by the callers of the function in which the variable is defined.